# How can I take a value from thread without future?

Tags: c++, multithreading, future

I wrote the program to count all words in .log files in the different threads and output the result on the screen.
 First argument in command line is dir to find all .log files and then count words in this files.
  Second argument in command line is number of threads (by default = 4)
I used the ThreadPool for this program

ThreadPool.h

```
#ifndef THREAD_POOL_H
#define THREAD_POOL_H

#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <future> // I don't how to work with boost future
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>


class ThreadPool
{
public:
    using Task = std::function<void()>; // Our task

    explicit ThreadPool(int num_threads)
    {
        start(num_threads);
    }

    ~ThreadPool()
    {
        stop();
    }

    template<class T>
    auto enqueue(T task)->std::future<decltype(task())>
    {
        // packaged_task wraps any Callable target
        auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task()) ()>>(std::move(task));

        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock{ mutex_p };
            tasks_p.emplace([=] {
                (*wrapper)();
            });
        }

        event_p.notify_one();
        return wrapper->get_future();
    }

    //void enqueue(Task task)
    //{
    //  {
    //      boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock { mutex_p };
    //      tasks_p.emplace(std::move(task));
    //      event_p.notify_one();
    //  }
    //}

private:
    std::vector<boost::thread> threads_p; // num of threads
    std::queue<Task>           tasks_p;   // Tasks to make
    boost::condition_variable  event_p; 
    boost::mutex               mutex_p;

    bool                       isStop = false;

    void start(int num_threads)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
        {
            // Add to the end our thread
            threads_p.emplace_back([=] {
                while (true)
                {
                    // Task to do
                    Task task;

                    {
                        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_p);

                        event_p.wait(lock, [=] { return isStop || !tasks_p.empty(); });

                        // If we make all tasks
                        if (isStop && tasks_p.empty())
                            break;

                        // Take new task from queue
                        task = std::move(tasks_p.front());
                        tasks_p.pop();
                    }

                    // Execute our task
                    task();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    void stop() noexcept
    {
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_p);
            isStop = true;
            event_p.notify_all();
        }

        for (auto& thread : threads_p)
        {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ThreadPool.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <vector>
#include <map>

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>


namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

int count_words(const std::string& filename)
{
    int counter = 0;
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::string buffer;
    while (file >> buffer)
    {
        ++counter;
    }
    
    return counter;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    bfs::path path = argv[1];
    // If this path is exist and if this is dir
    if (bfs::exists(path) && bfs::is_directory(path))
    {
        // Number of threads. Default = 4
        int n = (argc == 3 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 4);
        ThreadPool pool(n);

        // Container to store all filenames and number of words inside them
        std::map<bfs::path, int> all_files_and_sums;
        
        // Iterate all files in dir
        for (auto& p : bfs::directory_iterator(path)) {
            // Takes only .txt files
            if (p.path().extension() == ".log") {
                // Future for taking value from here
                auto fut = pool.enqueue([&p, &all_files_and_sums]() {
                    // In this lambda function I count all words in file and return this value
                    int result = count_words(p.path().string());
                    std::cout << "TID " << GetCurrentThreadId() << "\n";
                    return result;
                });
                // "filename = words in this .txt file"
                all_files_and_sums[p.path()] = fut.get();
            }
        }

        int result = 0;

        for (auto& k : all_files_and_sums)
        {
            std::cout << k.first << "- " << k.second << "\n";
            result += k.second;
        }

        std::cout << "Result: " << result << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::perror("Dir is not exist");
}
```

And this solution works correctly. But if in the directory many files this solution works so slow. I think it's because of the futures. How can I take values from different threads without futures.

(P.S)
Sorry for my english

Comment: `fut.get();` immediately  after the creation makes that most-inner series of ops no better than a standard function call. You're creating an async operation, then immediately waiting on it before moving to the next. Don't do that.

Comment: The bottleneck might be IO not async operations. You may read one by one and profile the time and compare it with the fix noted by WhozCraig.

Comment: Regarding my prior comment, i suggest you either (a) use a thread pool with a task-specific *queue* and don't use futures at all (more work for you, but control-levels as specific as you desire), or (b) use async futures entirely and just ditch the thread pool (i.e. let the async runtime consider pooling threads where appropriate and just load up a bunch of asyncs, reaping them later). Trying to mix them seems fruitless.